# Insert data from static ArrayList into table in mySql database

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Thank you in advance for any advice. I am having an ArrayList and trying to enter data to the mysql database. Error I am getting: 
**com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'Id' at row 1**
I checked item.id is max 2 characters, Id = varchar(3) in the table. I attached also screen shot to show you size of elements in the table. I do suspect some error in my code in the loop when I am assigning the values from the ArrayList to the table. Exactly I think it is some error in this part of the code in the class given below.

```
for(Contact item : pDir){
            s.execute("INSERT INTO pDB.Phone_D (Id, First_Name, 
                    Last_Name, Phone_Number) values ('item.id', 'item.firstName', 'item.lastName', 
                    'item.phoneNumber') ");
        }
</pre> </code>


<pre> <code>
public class Contact {


private static ArrayList<Contact> pDir;
private  String id, firstName, lastName, phoneNumber;
String dataSourceName = "pDB";
String dbURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/" + dataSourceName;
String result = "";
Connection con = null;
Statement s;

static{
pDirectory = new ArrayList<Contact>();
    Contact c0 = new Contact("1","Maaaaaa","Madreth","111-000-1998");
    Contact c1 = new Contact("2","Dara","Gurde","020-000-1996");
    Contact c2 = new Contact("3","Maaaaaa","Kvalskrooeee","100-111-1998");
    pDir.add(c0);
    pDir.add(c1);
    pDir.add(c2);   
}

public Contact() {
    for(Contact item : pDir) {
         System.out.println(item.id + " " + item.firstName + " " + item.lastName + " " +  
                 item.phoneNumber);
    }
}

public Contact(String id, String firstName, String lastName, String phoneNumber) {  
    this.id =id;
    this.firstName = firstName; 
    this.lastName = lastName; 
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
}

public String getFirstName() { return firstName;}
public void setFirstName(String firstName) { this.firstName = firstName;}
public String getLastName() { return lastName; }
public void setLastName(String lastName) { this.lastName = lastName; }
public String getId() { return id;}
public void setId(String id) {this.id = id;}
    public String getPhoneNumber() { return phoneNumber;}
    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) { this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;}

public Response getLocationDetails(         
    try {
        try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL,"root","password");
        System.out.println("We are connected to database");
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Can not connect to database");
        e.printStackTrace();
        }

                s = (Statement) con.createStatement();
        for(Contact item : pDir){
            s.execute("INSERT INTO pDB.Phone_D (Id, First_Name, 
                    Last_Name, Phone_Number) values ('item.id', 'item.firstName', 'item.lastName', 
                    'item.phoneNumber') ");
        }
         }
}
```

Screenshot of the tablePhone_D

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `'item.id'` to `'"+item.id+"'` in the `INSERT` query (and other values).
Moreover I'd recommend you to use [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) instead.

Comment: Hi Alex. Thank you. It worked. Could you please explain what does "+ +" do? I see positive changes and solving my issue.

Comment: In your case you used text "item.id". But you need to use variable `item.id` as above.

Comment: Please see examples here (Concatenating Strings -> Hello World example) http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html